# Execute jquery function after being redirected to another page

Tags: jquery, html, redirect, browser, page-refresh

I have an intro animation and a skip intro button on a homepage. If the user goes back to the homepage I don't want to run the animation again. Basically I want to treat the homepage nav button like the skip intro button. How would I do this if the page is redirecting back to the homepage. Can I redirect it home then run the "skip" function?

Comment: You could put in a cookie or session level variable that gets checked once they've viewed the intro or skipped it. Simply check for that cookie or session variable before displaying the intro.

Comment: you could also add a parameter to the url of the home link and only show the animation when the param is not set.

Comment: On page load the canvas animation function is executed and at the ending the animation intro elements are put in place. images and text fade in, etc. If the skip button is pressed another function is executed to skip animation and place the elements sooner. So I need the main intro function executed  only once per session and the skip function executed on page load the  rest of the session.